# How to find $\sum_{k=1}^n k^k$?

Tags: summation

Actually question which I found:

> Find the sum of the series $1^1+2^2+3^3+ \cdots +n^n $

This question has been bothering me since a long time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is http://oeis.org/A001923 .  Looks like there's no nice formula other than just doing it out.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^nk^k~\approx~n^n$

Comment: Is there any proof that the formula doesn't exist? I tried searching the web for it, but couldn't find.

Comment: @Sil Yeah it does. Is it a good idea to delete this post?

Comment: @Sil Okay, flagged!